# Logging library for (c++) games

Tags: c++, software-engineering, performance

I know a lot of logging libraries but didn't test a lot of them. (GoogleLog, Pantheios, the coming boost::log library...)

In games, especially in remote multiplayer and multithreaded games, logging is vital to debugging, even if you remove all logs in the end.

Let's say I'm making a PC game (not console) that needs logs (multiplayer and multithreaded and/or multiprocess) and I have good reasons for looking for a library for logging (like, I don't have time or I'm not confident in my ability to write one correctly for my case).

Assuming that I need :

1. performance
2. ease of use (allow streaming or formating or something like that)
3. reliable (don't leak or crash!)
4. cross-platform (at least Windows, MacOSX, Linux/Ubuntu)

Wich logging library would you recommand?

Currently, I think that boost::log is the most flexible one (you can even log to remotely!), <strike>but have not good performance</strike> update: is for high performance, but isn't released yet. Pantheios is often cited but I don't have comparison points on performance and usage. I've used my own lib for a long time but I know it don't manage multithreading so it's a big problem, even if it's fast enough. Google Log seems interesting, I just need to test it but if you already have compared those libs and more, your advice might be of good use.

Games are often performance demanding while complex to debug so it would be good to know logging libraries that, in our specific case, have clear advantages.

Comment: One requirement that matters that you didn't mention is what you intend to use the logs for. The requirements for logging, say, debug messages, metrics for designers, character state for customer support, and credit card transactions, are different. In general you trade off performance, ease of use for programmers, ease / speed of offline parsing, and durability depending on the situation.

Comment: That's right, but I was assuming that a "complete" logging solution would allow the users to setup different kind of logs like you describe. 
If you find this precision important in the question, please be my guest and add it to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[log using socket](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/) (any socket wrapper can suffice) + web browser [websocket](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) => most versatile, unobtrusive logging tool possible, will gain hours of debugging and avoid eye-sore.

- asyncrhonous (speed as it defers all the job on the browser)
- formatted (color, size etc..)
- reliable (sockets...)
- cross-platform (browser)

Now, the bonus:

- dynamic filtering very easily done (using javascript regex if needed)
- with log history, memory and compare (HTML5 spec on the "in-browser" database)
- Easy way to make some graph of any data (using SVG, or canvas or anything) like [memory](http://cbloomrants.blogspot.com/2010/08/08-25-10-profileparser.html), [memory fragmentation](http://blackpawn.com/blog/?p=305), etc...
- easy way to make some 2D graph of any data ([kd-tree subdivision](http://blackpawn.com/blog/?p=211) ? potential field ? or even just a variable value variation ? etc...)
- allows distant logging (using the browser other computer)
- using html5 in browser storage, you can store log session parameteres (current log filters, etc.. and even notes on each)
- very easy to create bug report or link trac tickets just with a click
- ability to rewind logging easily, with a [timeline gui](http://code.google.com/p/simile-widgets/)

and many more task outside of logging:

- allows profiler info (graphs...)
- can even serve as console (send command from browser) or even with quick GUI using some HTML or even flash ui
- image diff  in the browser (send image using socket, and compare in browser using canvas image pixel capabilities)
- etc...

(nearly all of the above can be done using flash sockets, save the database capabilities)

Now I know it seems a bit long to set up the thing. But it really is a gain of time on long project, with hard debugging situation (such as in games.) It's the most powerful thing I used since debuggers...

Note 1: the only downside => double-check side effect when debugging game networking code (impact on socket buffer size, latency, bandwidth, etc...)

Note 2: some broswer deactivated by default websocket due to security reason, check about:config things to be sure it's enabled.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this only suggests where to direct logging output to, no? A real logging library would also allow filtering at _compile-time_ (which is crucial if performance is an issue), formatting, and provide an easy-to-use syntax for creating log messages.

Comment: @sbi It's a global on or off thing on the application side. "Browser log client" does the filtering, syntax, but it always get all the log. It's radical, but it's based on the experience that during dev, you should always log everything so that you can catch/reproduce easily any bugs you stumble upon.  If you have to optimize, it's browser side again : Using socket you're not bound to log using string, you can directly log binary data (Id + floats), which is **bold** faster than any other string based log lib...(matching Id to string browser side...)

Comment: While I can see that this is very practical, it's really just a logger's backend (what templog calls a "log sink", IIRC). Performance is one of the requirements listed. I have found that I need to add log statements to a piece of code while debugging it, but once it's up and running this piece of code would be too talkative and drown whatever I'm working on then in its noise, and would also cost too much performance. So I want to be able to tone up and down the log level on whole pieces of code with changing a few lines of code. That's what a log lib's middle layer does for you.

Comment: @sbi: may require benchmarks, but there's chance that the best logging library, even at the lowest logging level, still costs you more than a binary logger that logs everything. There is not even a single "binary to char" CPU Cycle wasted... So it's really more feature AND more performance.

Comment: Before we decided to actually use templog, we made some tests. If logging is turned off for the severity, origin, or whatnot of a specific log message, and if the compiler is able to find out that there are no side effects in evaluating the parameters, then VC is indeed able to optimize a full-blown log statement into nothingness. And when it comes to speed, you won't beat code that isn't there to be executed in the first place.

Comment: The more boost::log release is coming, and it seems "fast" so far, the more I think mixing boost::log and this solution is good. I'll have to test that.

Answer (score 8):

When it comes to performance, I've found [templog](http://www.templog.org) pretty much unbeaten. It uses expression templates to defer evaluation of logging statements until it's established that the information will be logged at all. Since you can also partly turn off logging (depending on severity, origin, and targeted audience of a log message), some of these logging statement can be eliminated to zero code by the compiler for release builds. (I have actually seen this happen with VC.)

There wasn't much done to the library recently, and others on SO have found the trunk lacking in some regards, but in a company I used to work for we have found the guy quite responsive, and one of my then cow-workers even got commit access and added some code to it, so you might find it worth a shot.

To enumerate your requirements:

> performance

Best I've found. Especially its ability to exclude log messages *at compile-time* and have the compiler completely eliminate those was very appealing.

> ease of use (allow streaming or formating or something like that)

There's the classical horrible compiler error messages of templates-meta stuff when you do something wrong, but when it comes to ease of use, this

```
TEMPLOG_LOG(my_logger,sev_error,aud_support) << "logged in as " << user_name;
```

is hard to beat.
However, you might have to create your own log sinks (that's where the log messages go), as the few pre-packaged ones (stderr, file, Windows logging, etc.) aren't all that sophisticated. 
Due to performance being a main goal, the intrinsics of the whole thing are somewhat complicated (like log message formatters being quite tangled with log sinks), but we did master that (I remember stepping through it in a debugger helping with that) and once understood it wasn't all that hard to write your own message formatters or log sinks.

> reliable (don't leak or crash!)

We have used it without finding any such severe issues. There's virtually no dynamic memory allocation in there, so it's hard to even imagine it doing something wrong. Of course, we only ever put it to real-world tests in one product.

> cross-platform (at least Windows, MacOSX, Linux/Ubuntu)

When we used it, we used it on Win32, OSX, and several different Linux distributions, Ubuntu among them.

As for multi-threading: We haven't used this, but from what I remember of the lib's architecture it seems you would only need to handle this in log sinks. ICBWT.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this one. It looks like a simplified (and performant) version of boost::log, at least in the original idea.

Comment: @Klaim: I don't think boost had anything to offer when I last looked into C++ logging libraries, so I don't know about boost::log.

Comment: @sbi: Yeah it's "accepted" as a boost library but not released yet, need some fixes. You can find it there : http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html

Comment: @Joe: Can you elaborate? AFAICS templog doesn't use IO streams.

Comment: @sbl: Since `foo << a << b` ends up calling foo.operator<< twice, there's no way to make the API threadsafe without special "unlock" tokens at the end, which no one implements and no one would remember to use if they did. It's a fundamental problem caused by iostreams-like interfaces trying to handle copy _and_ formatting _and_ ioctls with the same interface. C-like interfaces do not have this problem; either you sprintf ahead of time, or you use something like fprintf, which can lock/unlock the stream's mutex for exactly its execution lifetime.

Comment: @Joe: __I think you are wrong__. Have you even looked at the code? That `operator<<` does not do any output, it only contributes to an expression tree, which is then passed _at once_ through several layers, might be discarded by any of them if compile-time filtering matches, and ends up in code that filters at run-time. If it makes it through filtering, it will be formatted and written by the formatting and write policy you use. Whether this is thread-safe depends on those, and you can provide your own. The lib doesn't impose mutex performance loss on users, but doesn't hinder it either.

Comment: @sbi: I haven't read templog's code. But unless there is some way to tell via C++ magic I can't think of that `b` terminates the expression and `a` does not, it doesn't matter whether it's going to "real" output or not. The problem is not that iostreams is not threadsafe (but it's basically not) - the problem is that anything that _looks like_ iostreams, which includes templog, also can't be threadsafe. It's a fundamental issue with the API design.

Comment: @Joe: Do you understand the term _"expression templates"_??

Comment: I thought I did, but now I have downloaded and started reading the templog source code, and it appears C++ has outwitted me again.

Comment: @Joe: What that `operator<<` does is to create an _expression tree_ with all the operands chained. That tree is passed down all the way to your formatting policy. That policy will then traverse the tree and write its items using the write policy. Now that I again looked closer at this, there's incremental and non-incremental write policies. The former incrementally write as they traverse the expression tree, the latter stream into a string stream first and write the content of that _at once_. Using a non-incremental write policy your threads should be home and dry by default.

Comment: @sbi: Part of my confusion was your statement "passed at once through several layers" - In English _at once_ can mean either _immediately_ or _together_, which in this case are opposites. I read it as the first, and you (now obviously to me) meant the second. Thanks for taking the time to explain it.

Comment: @Joe: Sorry for the confusion, I'm a non-native. `:(` Anyway, thank _you_ for this civil argument, a welcome change for the all-too-often bickering I see on the SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to consider the logog library, at http://www.logog.org , which I think may satisfy your requirements.  Caveat: I wrote it.

See also other people's answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696321/best-logging-framework-for-native-c .

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [Baical](http://www.baical.net) tools set:

- Open source and cross platform (Win, Linux, x86/x64) library for logs, traces & telemetry - [P7](http://www.baical.net/p7.html)
- Incredibly fast (designed for embedded devices) - 3 million of logs per second to network, 5 millions to file on modern CPU. I don't know any other library for logging which provides such speed and so detailed information for every log message.
- Thread safe
- Every trace message contains:

  - text message
  - level
  - precise time (100ns)
  - source file, function name & line
  - module ID and module name
  - thread ID and thread name
  - processor core index
- Server application to receive and view logs & telemetry
- You may collect, analyze, search, filter logs from multiple sources in real-time

Comment: As of 06/2017 %s in string formatting is not supported yet.